# Android and Themes (I'm not an expert)

Tags: untagged

I was wondering, whether, there is a mechanism, in Android, to enable cross-app theming.

For instance, I could launch the theming app, and use it to color app icon and app icon backgrounds, as well as app components, whatever color, I wanted to.

This would have to be supported at the application-system layer.

It could also be possible to download different themes (for instance, from a repository, embedded in the app. This, could, at a minimum, allow, users (to mock around)).

To the best, of my knowledge, currently, only the background and screen saver photograph, can be changed.

Is there an app that does what I am wondering about, on, Android?

Thank you for your answers and support.

I think this might also help to establish certain thinking patterns or preferences.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in mechanism for cross-app theming in Android. However, there are a few ways to achieve this like **Use a custom theme engine**, **Use a launcher** or **Use a custom interface**

I am not aware of any app that does exactly what you are wondering about. However, there are a number of apps that allow you to customize the appearance of your device, such as Substratum, Nova Launcher, and Lawnchair Launcher.

I agree that cross-app theming would be a useful feature. It would allow users to create a more cohesive look for their devices. It would also allow developers to provide more customization options for their users.